# SSRS: Cannot read the next data row for the dataset hexadecimal value 0x02, is an invalid character

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

Can anyone please help me I get the following error only on one value of the parameter in SSRS Report and it works for all the rest:SSRS: Cannot read the next data row for the dataset. hexadecimal value 0x02, is an invalid character .

The SSRS Report works from SSAS Cubes. The Parameter that it fails on is simply a list of Insurer Names of varchar Value and I cannot spot any ascii characters
in the actual data. As I said it works for the rest of the Insurers ...I also cannot seem to find a solution to this anywhere.

Comment: If you want to add more information to your question use the "edit" button (below the question tags) instead of adding a comment.

Comment: What if you removed the Insurer's ID from your SSRS Report?  Or do a conversion on it?  Like a STR or STRING..  If you don't do that, the report will try to treat is a HEX value.  something like: Fields!FullDateAlternateKey.Value)/7)+1).ToString   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx#VisualBasicFunctions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an invalid character in your data.

I didn't test this solution but one suggestion to solve this issue is to change `InvalidXMLCharacters` property in your data source in the database. It should be possible to select `Remove` or `Replace`. Please see more details [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ChrisAlbrektson/bidn-blog/1142/the-server-sent-an-unrecognizable-response).